# add image to list from fileupload Asp control by using JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online

i have list called SharesList has image column, so i need to make the end user upload image from his/her local pc... please i need any solutions immediately.

```
        var siteUrl = '/deanships/6thgraduation';
        var uploadedURL, itemTitle;
        function updateListItem(itemTitle,uploadedURL) {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('SharesList');
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            oListItem.set_item('Title', itemTitle);
            oListItem.set_item('test', uploadedURL);

            oListItem.update();
            clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }

        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            alert('Item updated!');
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery Add-in : http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/

We recently worked on a similar solution. In our case we already had a REST WCF service so it was easier to add a new API with 1 single 'Stream' parameter and then use the above add-in, which basically creates an iframe with multipart form and then posts the data to a WCF Service.
The service receives the data in stream and it needs to be decoded as stated here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/7a387bc1-fb7a-4c7b-a17f-19fc167f9621.

Hope this helps,
Jomit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcimaging.imaging.upload.aspx

I haven't really seen ECMAScript examples uploading files in SharePoint. Either use a Silverlight Control or one of the Web Services to handle content. Client Object Model comes in many shapes (Managed, ECMA and Silverlight - each with its own constraints and limitations).

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will check it but i think it's helpful, but can i add item from picture library to list by javascript or JQuery ?

Comment: If you would manage to wrap it around the call for the Web Service, yes you can. See here for an example http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/